# Can't read cookie except in IE

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

I can read the following cookie in firebug:

> FIXXLY_ID=Niflj34FiodrgRTk0MWQtMWQzMTYxNDE5MTVh|1377513181|4f983fa4ca9c0554hfd6dcb24d1a3188a9d3fa2; expires=Wed, 25 Sep 2013 10:33:01 GMT; Path=/; Domain=mysub.mydomain.pt

The request comes from `http://mysub.mydomain.com/myapp/#/login`

BUT I can't read the cookie with javascript when I use FF, Chrome, Safari. ONLY IE works. I tried to read the cookie using document.cookie, jquery's `$.cookie()` and also `angularjs-cookies`. The cookie is NOT HttpOnly.

I tried setting the cookie domain to `.mydomain.pt` and `mydomain.pt`.
I also tried to set `Path=/myapp`.
I read other posts here in StackOverflow but couldn't find an answer to this.

The cookie is being set on a different server/domain!

What I'm am I missing here? Anyone? Thanks.

Comment: Does it show up in `document.cookie`? Was the page reloaded after the cookie has been set? Sometimes cookies set during an AJAX request do not show up on the originating page unless it has been reloaded afterwards.

Comment: it only shows up in document.cookie if I use IE :|

Comment: I do a AJAX request (using angularjs), the server sets the cookie and sends it back. The page is not reloaded anytime.

Comment: Does it work when you reload it?

Comment: How would I do that? Force a reloading of the page after I get the response from the server to see if the cookie is available using document.cookie?

Comment: Yes, or just hit f5 and then check if it's in `document.cookie`

Comment: Have you configured those other browsers to accept third-party cookies?

Comment: ThiefMaster: I did that. It doesn't show up.

Comment: Alvaro: firefox is accepting all cookies.

Comment: Are you using the actual jquery cookie plugin? Jquery doesn't have a native $.cookie, and the plugin at https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie has worked across all browsers for me.

Comment: That's what is weird :| I am using that plugin from github but still it doesn't work. It should have worked with angularjs too... Someone told me it should be something to do with the domain and/or path set on the cookie. I just realized I forgot (oops) to mention that the cookie was being set in a different server/domain!! I just updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The problem was in the ports used.
What was happening was that the requests were being made to port 8081 (there was a proxy forwarding requests to the final destination, listening in port 8081), but apparently only IE has no problemas with that port for http requests. So we changed our nginx server (in http://mysub.mydomain.com) to redirect the requests to port 80.

I know I didn't say anything about ports or the proxy in my question, but that's because I don't know enough about cookies and didn't think it had anything to do with it - my bad. 
And sorry for that. Anyway, this was the solution to my problem.